Is Harry Potter being watched in Harry Potter and the Prisoner of Azkaban?
In Harry Potter and the Prisoner of Azkaban, Harry is in (apparent) danger from Sirius Black. In Order of the Phoenix, when Harry is in danger from Voldemort, Dumbledore has people continually watching Harry to ensure his safety.
I can think of one place in Prisoner of Azkaban that this might have also occured, as Dumbledore would want to ensure Harry's safety: his stay in Diagon Alley.
Is there any proof that Dumbledore had people watching Harry anywhere in Harry Potter and the Prisoner of Azkaban to ensure his safety?

Sirius Black is not as sirius of a problem as Lord Voldemort is.

Well in HP3 the Ministry of Magic is already somewhat watching over Harry Potter by deploying the Dementors in the place where they believed Sirius Black was most likely to turn up, so we might even make the argument that additional measures are unnecessary. More generally, a notable difference between Sirius in HP3 and Voldemort in HP5 is that, in HP5, the Ministry is not looking for Voldemort.

@Mini88881 But Dumbledore has a sirius reason to do so.

@Gae.S. That is a good point. Although, in HP3, the ministry is doing a pretty bad job of it. But I don't think Dumbledore trusts the ministry's abilities either.

I suspect Dumbledore might have known Sirius was trustworthy

@Clockwork Either he didn't, or it didn't benefit him enough to help Sirius: https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/222268/was-sirius-blacks-innocence-always-known-to-dumbledore

No More Than Usual
There is no direct evidence to support the fact that Dumbledore sent anyone to watch Harry upon the escape of Sirius Black.  Nor, I think, would there have been any need.
At first, Harry is living at Privet Drive, and by everything we can see does not leave the house while on break.  Since the house is protected from Voldemort/his supporters by Lily's spell, Sirius can't get at him.  Guards might even be a detriment in that situation.
After Harry runs away he's quickly found and set up in the Leaky Cauldron and told to stay in Diagon Ally.  He's literally surrounded by adult wizards to include friends/associates of Dumbledore, so no need for Dumbledore to post a specific guard.
Then Harry's at school, and at that point with Dementors guarding the perimeter and teachers around there is again no need for a specific guard.
I'll point out that Mrs. Figg, Harry's squib neighbor, is known to be friends with Dumbledore and based on scenes from Harry Potter and the Order of the Phoenix onward may have been proving Dumbledore updates on Harry's doings.  So I would assume she'd be keeping Dumbledore apprised of the goings-on at Privet Drive and if Harry'd taken to wandering around alone perhaps a guard would have been set.
